# Web scraping using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, web-scraping

I wrote a code to lookup for some movie names on IMDB, but if for instance I am searching for "Harry Potter", I will find more than one movie. I would like to use multithreading, but I don't have much knowledge on this area.

I am using strategy design pattern to search among more websites, and for instance inside one of the methods I have this code

```
            for (Element element : elements) {
            String searchedUrl = element.select("a").attr("href");
            String movieName = element.select("h2").text();
            if (movieName.matches(patternMatcher)) {
                Result result = new Result();
                result.setName(movieName);
                result.setLink(searchedUrl);
                result.setTitleProp(super.imdbConnection(movieName));
                System.out.println(movieName + " " + searchedUrl);
                resultList.add(result);
            }
        }
```

which, for each element (which is the movie name), will create a new connection on IMDB to lookup for ratings and other stuff, on the `super.imdbConnection(movieName)` line.

The problem is, I would like to have all the connections at the same time, because on 5-6 movies found, the process will take much longer than expected.

I am not asking for code, I want some ideeas. I thought about creating an inner class which implements Runnable, and to use it, but I don't find any meaning on that.

How can I rewrite that loop to use multithreading?

I am using Jsoup for parsing, Element and Elements are from that library.

Comment: From what library is `Element`? Also, how we are suppose to know what `super.imdbConnection(...)` do?

Comment: Element is from Jsoup, sorry for that. Also, imdbConnection is another method, it is estabilishing a connection to IMDB, and looks up for rating, descripting, trailer and genre. I don't have anything that can be made faster there :(.

I will edit my question and specify that, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way is `parallelStream()`

```
List<Result> resultList = elements.parallelStream()
                                  .map(e -> {
            
                                      String searchedUrl = element.select("a").attr("href");
                                      String movieName = element.select("h2").text();

                                      if(movieName.matches(patternMatcher)){

                                          Result result = new Result();
                                          result.setName(movieName);
                                          result.setLink(searchedUrl);
                                          result.setTitleProp(super.imdbConnection(movieName));
                                          
                                          System.out.println(movieName + " " + searchedUrl);

                                          return result;

                                      }else{
                                          return null;
                                      }

                                  }).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't like `parallelStream()` and want to use Threads, you can to this:

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

//create a function which returns an implementation of `Callable`
//input: Element
//output: Callable<Result>
Function<Element, Callable<Result>> scrapFunction = (element) -> new Callable<Result>() {

    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception{

        String searchedUrl = element.select("a").attr("href");
        String movieName = element.select("h2").text();
        if(movieName.matches(patternMatcher)){

            Result result = new Result();
            result.setName(movieName);
            result.setLink(searchedUrl);
            result.setTitleProp(super.imdbConnection(movieName));
            
            System.out.println(movieName + " " + searchedUrl);

            return result;

        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }

};

//create a fixed pool of threads
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(elements.size());

//submit a Callable<Result> for every Element
//by using scrapFunction.apply(...)
List<Future<Result>> futures = elements.stream()
                                        .map(e -> executor.submit(scrapFunction.apply(e)))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

//collect all results from Callable<Result>
List<Result> resultList = futures.stream()
                                .map(e -> {
                                    try{
                                        return e.get();
                                    }catch(Exception ignored){
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It works like a charm :). I guess I will start learning about streams and more multithreading! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @scrapplez, I updated my answer. I added the way using threads. Also, there can be many ways using threads.

Comment: Thank you one more time! Also, thank you for comments on the second one.

Comment: @scrapplez, Welcome. If it's hard for you to understand, feel free to ask.